# How to store previous 30 days and next 30 days data?

Tags: mysql, database-design, cron, time-series, nosql

[image: flight booking company display data of cheapest flight of each day]

Suppose I have 100 items whose price vary daily. Say today is 11 sep 2017, I want to store price for these 100 items for last 30 days and next 30 days say from 11 Aug 2017 to 11 Oct 2017. If I opt for every date as a column name then I will have 100 rows ( 1 row per Item) and each row will have 60 column ( each column will display data for that day price ). Now after today ends, I have to delete column corresponding to  11 Aug and add column corresponding to 12 Oct. Should I use Cron for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose rational database then it is trivial task, you just need to created a table that link product price with date.

One for example:

```
| productId | day        | price  |
| 1         | 11-09-2017 | 50.25  |
| 2         | 11-09-2017 | 12.50  |
```

Comment: How should I deal with deleting the data. Suppose on Sep 12, Aug11 data will not be required, So should I fetch every row corresponding Aug11 and delete them. If yes then How should I automate this task ? I mean like every new day one day data has to be scrapped off from the database.

Comment: You will need to run `DELETE` query every day: `DELETE FROM dailyPrices WHERE day + INTERVAL 30 DAY <= NOW()`

Comment: More common approach is to mark the records you don't need as not active or archived. Add another column for this, for example isActive type `ENUM` with values "yes/no". And when you fetch data pick only thous records that are marked as "active". Then you will just update the flag on outdated records: `UPDATE dailyPrices SET isActive="no" WHERE day + INTERVAL 30 DAY <= NOW()`

Comment: Should I use Cron to drop a column every day( for the column that falls below the mark of 30 day) and add a column that adds up the new date

Comment: No, it would a horrible table structure. Ideally table structure should never change. When you will have lots of data in your table structure changing `ALTER`s will take a lot of time and will lock table for read-write operations.

Answer (score 0):

NO!  60 rolling rows in a table, not 60 rolling columns.

It is easy to `INSERT` and `DELETE` a row each day.  It is messy to do the same with columns.

The table would have (at least):  (date, item_id, price)